# jquery Ajax - how to replicate posting a button with a name, on changing a select element (dynamic key name in ajax request)

Tags: jquery, html

I have an application which works as follows:

1. User selects 1 or more customers using a table and series of checkboxes.
2. One of four buttons can be pressed; each has a different `name` parameter, for example `<button name="schedule_btn">`
3. When the user presses a button on (2) a POST is made to a PHP script, `/email-attendees`. This happens without jQuery; it is a normal PHP page-reload style post.
4. After (3) the page is rendered based on the POST data passed to it. It requires certain data (at least one of the 4 buttons - see PHP code below, and some other data including the customers selected in (1) ).

Based on the button selected in (2) content for an email template is loaded during (3) and then rendered in a WYSIWYG editor on the page at (4).

I'm trying to adapt my page (4) so it has a `select` dropdown where it's possible to toggle the email template to be used.

The way I envisaged this working is by mimicking the POST request to `/email-attendees` but passing in the `name` parameter of the button from (2).

**The problem I'm having is I can't work out how to dynamically pass the button's `name` *as a key* in my ajax request.**

The dropdown looks like this:

```
<select id="scheduleTemplate">
    <option value="schedule_btn">Existing customer</option>
    <option value="new_customer_schedule_btn">New customer</option>
    <!-- some more options -->
</select>
```

What I'm trying to do is reference the `option` value, but POST it such that PHP will read it like in the code below. This is basically saying is there a POST variable with a given name (e.g. 'schedule_btn' or 'new_customer_schedule_btn'):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['schedule_btn'])) {

    }
    if (isset($_POST['new_customer_schedule_btn'])) {

    }
?>
```

The reason I'm having to do this is because that's how the existing `/email-attendees` logic has been written and I can't adapt it because it impacts on other parts of the application.

I've tried doing this in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#scheduleTemplate" ).change(function() {
        var template = $('#scheduleTemplate').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/email-attendees",
            data: { template : true },
            method: "POST",
          }).done(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
          });
    });
});
```

This doesn't work, presumably because jQuery thinks I'm passing a data variable called "template" whereas I need it that variable to be the dynamic `name` of the select option.

*Edit: The desired outcome is like this, but obviously I'm hard-coding this and it's not dynamic or based on my select option. The actual names ('schedule_btn' etc) need to be dynamic from the selected option in `#scheduleTemplate`*

```
data: {'schedule_btn' : true }
```

or

```
data: {'new_customer_schedule_btn' : true }
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just send it like that:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/email-attendees",
   data: template, // WITHOUT BRACES
   method: "POST",
 }).done(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

and if for example `template = "black"` then `(isset($_POST['black']))` will be `true`

Other thing you can do is check is send information that the request is ajax and swap data you need, for example

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/email-attendees",
   data: {"template": template, "action" => "ajax"},
   method: "POST",
 }).done(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

Then in php before any other logic

```
if(isSet($_POST['ajax'])) {
   $_POST[$_POST['template']] = 1;
}
```

This is messy way, far better would be to refactor current logic IMO.

Comment: Have you tested this? Because it doesn't work, and is not really any different to what I already have. PHP just sees a POST variable called 'template'... which isn't what I need. Also, it's the *key* I'm interested in, not the *value*.

Comment: @Andy Yes i tested this, it works as should, the diffrent is you use `template` as key in object which is interpreted as string key not variable

Comment: Ok I think you've mis-understood what I'm trying to do. The *key* (`template` in this case) has to be dynamic, and come from whatever is selected in my dropdown. When it comes to the ajax request, the *key* has to be dynamic, so PHP knows it's set. The value at that point however is irrelevant, which is why I just put 'true' in my code, so PHP knows there's a variable by that name (*key*) in the post. In your example it's more like saying `black: something`... but you can't hard-code `black` because it has to be dynamic.

Comment: What actually gets posted in your answer is `template:schedule_new_customer_btn` whereas what I need is `schedule_new_customer_btn:anything`. The `anything` part is irrelevant, because I only need to know there is a key with the name `schedule_new_customer_btn`. But... those keys cannot be hard-coded in the script because their names come from whatever is chosen in the select (`#scheduleTemplate`)

Comment: @Andy You realy tried that? What you got from `var_dump($_POST);` after send above ajax? In my snippet `$_POST['black'] = ''` or `$_POST['what_ever_template_name'] = ''` if you check that whatever key you set in template variable it'll return `true`

Comment: When I var_dump it, I get `["template"]=>
  string(25) "schedule_new_customer_btn"`. Re-read the 4th comment on this (which starts "what actually gets posted") and you'll understand the issue. The issue being `template` needs to be  `schedule_new_customer_btn` but I cannot hard-code any of this into the request. The key (`schedule_new_customer_btn`) must be dynamic based on the form selection. If this is what I want, it would look like `["schedule_new_customer_btn"]=> true`

Comment: @Andy I understand what you want to achieve, there is no way when you pass data like that `data: template` WITHOUT braces, that it returns like `$_POST['template']=> '...'`

Comment: I've posted an answer. I've no idea whether it's good or bad practice but it works.

Answer (score 0):

So after some experimentation the desired outcome can be achieved like this:

```
data: { [template]:true }
```

However, I've no idea whether that's good/bad practice.

But this means that the key name is dynamic because `template` is evaluated from

```
var template = $('#scheduleTemplate').val();
```

Comment: It work as well as `data: template` until you don't need passing any value just key, which fit your case

Comment: The square braces round `[template]` are what make all the difference. In your answer the POST key will always be the string "template", followed by it's value. In my case the string "template" is never seen by PHP, because it's always a dynamic name. Not sure if I've explained myself well enough to make that point, but I was always only wanting the key name, and for it to be dynamic.

Comment: Man i don't want to argue with you but i'm telling you that in my example thing that make all the diffrence is no braces at all, in this case `template` cant be used as string, as same as in your try with wrapping `template` inside array collection. I tried my example with diffrent browsers to be sure that is works not only on chrome, and result was the same